# VSCode extension indicators if extension is enabled only in workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I remember some time ago some of my extensions would show an indicator icon that the extension is enabled or installed only for current workspace (ex. not enabled globally)

Right now I don't see these indicator icons in my extension view, the only indicators I see are the small blue check marks identifying verified publishers:

[image]

My question is:

How do I enable viewing indicators in similar manner to show if extension is installed\enabled in current workspace only?

Btw. when I hover over extensions I see they say `this extension is enabled globally` but there aren't any indicator icons.

Secondary question, how do you make an extension not enabled globally but only for workspace?

**EDIT:**

I've found the following link which shows some indicators when searching for and filtering extensions, it seems no such indicators exist when there is no filter applied?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace

Comment: if the extension is dimmed it is disabled in this workspace, 2nd question: disable globally, open workspace and go to extension page and enable for workspace

Comment: Your answer to my 2nd question works, thanks for that, but dimmed extension is unrelated to my question about indicators telling if extension is workspace only.

Comment: you don't install extensions in a workspace, what is the information of knowing the extension is only enabled for this workspace. VSC needs to browse all workspace storage to get this info (I have a lot of workspaces), it only needs to know if the extension IS enabled for THIS workspace so only browse global storage and this workspace storage. If done otherwise you would complain VSC takes a long time to open a workspace, or that my extension X is not activated at open time but a lot later